# Downgrade to Windows 7 after Windows 10 upgrade on Asus X54C laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, asus-laptop

I've been trying to do a Factory Reset on this Asus X54C laptop and I can't get it to go back to Windows 7, which it came with. I *think* there is a recovery partition on the drive still, which I'm accessing via F9 at boot, but to complicate matters further, everything there is in Spanish. Doing my best to translate the options there, the best I've been able to do is a fresh install of Windows 10.

I tried downloading the Windows 7 ISO from Microsoft with the machine's product key but Microsoft isn't accepting an OEM product key.

I'm looking for some *legal* way to get this machine back on Windows 7 without having to buy a new copy.

Comment: "I tried downloading the Windows 7 ISO from Microsoft with the machine's product key but Microsoft isn't accepting an OEM product key." - Are you downloading the exact same version ( Professional, Home, Ect.) and Language of Windows 7 that originally game with the system?  You can always use the generic Windows 7 key, then change the key after the Windows is installed, and activate by phone.

Comment: I've been trying to get this ISO from this page, which starts by asking for your product key. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: See my answer on how to download Windows 7 legally.  You are using the wrong source for the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SHOULD be able to do this with almost no work :)
Go to your settings, click on updates and security, go to recovery then select go bac to windows 7. If you don't have a windows.old folder on your C drive this isn't possible.
You can also do it without this folder, but rather than typing it up I'll point out this excellent tutorial:
http://www.howtogeek.com/220723/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-downgrade-to-windows-7-or-8.1/

Comment: If I hadn't already tried to do the factory reset which ended up doing a fresh W10 install this may have been an option. Too late now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Click the start menu and select "Settings". Then, click update and security icon and click "Recovery". You should see something that says "Go back to windows 7". But if you have had Win10 for over a month, this feature is disabled. If it has been over a month, check out this guide.

[How to downgrade Windows 10 after a month](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-downgrade-windows-10-after-month-3631059/)